Why classList contains returns false after calling appendChild on a div element with JavaScript
I have a checkers project that I am trying to debug, I am using this logic to move pieces around. I play around with the CSS properties to remove pieces from previous boxes and add them to target boxes. Suppose player taps cell A which contains a gold piece then I use this code to check if the cell contains a gold piece
 if (event.target.classList.contains('gold-piece'));

This method returns true before that piece is moved but returns false on the newly tapped cell where the gold piece was moved. This is the logic am using to remove the gold-piece CSS style property from the original cell and add it to the new cell to create the illusion of a checkers move
 if (lastcell != null) {
     console.log("previous tapped cell is not null");
     //get the cell that was previously tapped
     //make sure the rows and the columns have a difference of 1
     let x1 = lastcell[0]; let y1 = lastcell[1];
     if (col < y1) {
         //it is a move towards the left
         if ((y1 - col) == 1 && (row - x1) == 1) {
             //the move is valid
             let original = getTableCell(table, x1, y1);
             let child = original.querySelector("div.gold-piece");;
             if (child != null) {
                 original.removeChild(child);
             }
             //move the piece to the target cell
             let target = getTableCell(table, row, col);
             const div = document.createElement("div");
             div.classList.add("gold-piece");
             target.appendChild(div);
             B = true;
             A = false;
         } else {
             console.log("the move is not valid");
             A = true;
             B = false;
             //clear the dictionary after a move
             lastTappedA = {}
         }
     } else {
         //it is a move towards the right
         if ((col - y1) == 1 && (row - x1) == 1) {
             //the move is valid
             let original = getTableCell(table, x1, y1);
             let child = original.querySelector("div.gold-piece");;
             if (child != null) {
                 original.removeChild(child);
             }
             //move the piece to the target cell
             let target = getTableCell(table, row, col);
             const div = document.createElement("div");
             div.classList.add("gold-piece");
             target.appendChild(div);
             B = true;
             A = false;
             lastTappedA = {}
         } else {
             console.log("the move is not valid");
             A = true;
             B = false;
         }
     }

 }

I programmatically create a child div element and then I add the gold piece style to it and then append it to the target cell, then I remove the the gold piece from the original cell using removeChild but when I tap on the new cell where the gold piece was added then the line event.target.classList.contains('gold-piece') returns false despite that cell having a gold-piece element.
I expected the new cell where the gold piece using the element.appendChild() method to return true, instead it is returning false, why is this and how can I resolve the issue?
The full code is below, tap on a yellow piece and make a move then tap on a red piece and make a move then go back to the original yellow piece you tapped and notice that it is not highlighted in white which means the line event.target.classList.contains('gold-piece') is returning false
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="playerA"></div>
    <table id="checkertable"></table>
    <div id="playerA"></div>
</body>
</html>

CSS
body{
    background:green;
}
/*style the table*/
.table{
    margin:auto;
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
}
.square{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.white{
    background-color:mintcream;
}
.brown{
    background-color:chocolate;
}
/*styles for the pieces*/
.gold-piece {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: gold;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10%;
}

.red-piece {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color:orangered;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10%;
}

/*style for styling a selected piece*/
.selected-piece{
   border:2px solid white;
}

JS
goldpiece.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (A) {
        if (event.target.classList.contains('gold-piece')) {
            //means the cell contains a piece
            console.log("gold piece tapped");
            //highlight this piece and remove highlights from any previous square
            const goldpieces = document.querySelectorAll('.gold-piece');
            console.log(goldpieces.length);
            goldpieces.forEach(function (element) {
                if (element.classList.contains('selected-piece')) {
                    //remove the highlight from previous cells
                    element.classList.remove('selected-piece');
                }
            });
            event.target.classList.add('selected-piece');
            //check if the piece can make a jump over opponent pieces
            let canJump = canJumpOverOpponent(table, row, col);
            if (canJump) {
                //this yellow piece can jump over opponent piece
                console.log("yellow piece can jump over red piece");
                //chek the direction of the capture
                let x1 = row + 1; let y1 = col - 1; let x2 = row + 1; let y2 = col + 1;
                let cellA = getTableCell(table, x1, y1);
                let cellB = getTableCell(table, x2, y2);
                let red = cellA.querySelector("div.red-piece");
                let redr = cellB.querySelector("div.red-piece");
                if (red != null && redr != null) {
                    //this yellow piece can capture in both directions
                    console.log("this piece can capture in both directions");
                    //update the variable that tells the player A to complete a capture
                    captureAStarted = true;
                    //write the cell to the dictionary
                    lastTappedA["lasttap"] = [row, col];
                    //exchange turns
                    A = false;
                    B = true;
                } else if (red != null && redr == null) {
                    //this piece is capturing towards the left
                    console.log("this piece can capture towards the left");
                    captureAStarted = true;
                    lastTappedA["lasttap"] = [row, col];
                    A = false;
                    B = true;
                } else if (red == null && redr != null) {
                    console.log("this piece can can capture towards the right");
                    captureAStarted = true;

                    lastTappedA["lasttap"] = [row, col];
                    A = false;
                    B = true;
                } else {
                    //means this piece canno capture
                    console.log("this piece cannot capture, checking if it can move");
                }
            } else {
                console.log("this piece cannot capture, checking if it can move");
                if (canYellowPieceMove(table, row, col)) {
                    console.log("this yellow piece can move");
                    lastTappedA["lasttap"] = [row, col];
                    A = true; B = false;
                    captureAStarted = false;
                } else {
                    console.log("this yellow piece cannot move");
                }
            }

        } else {

            console.log("piece does not contain a gold piece");
        }
    } else {
        console.log("it is the turn of player two");
    }
});

I found it, the error is I told my code to execute the function for a gold piece whenever the row is less than 3, I should move the block outside the if block and my code should work
//this conditional structure is the problem because it will check 
//and return false whenever a piece moves to row 3 or greater
if (row < 3) {
    const goldpiece = document.createElement('div');
    goldpiece.classList.add('gold-piece');
    newCell.appendChild(goldpiece);
    goldpiece.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        if (A) {


Your browser is not broken, so if it doesn't think that the event target has the class, then it doesn't.

@Pointy, how does the appendChild method work,, why is it returning false when I tap on a cell that contains a gold piece like it originally did before moving to the new cell?

You'll have to do some debugging. Clearly, event.target is not the element you think it is.

You haven't shown us enough of the code. Where is the event listener added? Making a snippet we can run will help find the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@Pointy, event.target is any cell tapped on., so I check if the cell has a gold piece by checking if that cell contains that css style, originally tapping on a cell , event.target.contains() returns true but then doesn't on clicking the new cell

@AHaworth, Editing so you can test and help me trace the anomalies

@AnthonyKinyua you have to abandon your assumptions and actually determine what is happening in your code.

Please include all relevant code.  eg you state event.target.classList.contains('gold-piece') but there's no event handlers in the provided code for event.target to be anything.   From your description "when I tap on the new cell" the event.target would be the cell - but without your code, that's just an assumption from your description.   If it is the cell, then, no, that cell will not have class gold-piece because the gold-piece class is added to the div inside the cell and .classList only applies to the element that you call it on.

Repeating - where are you adding the event listener for the new div?

@AHaworth, I haven't added a new event listener when creating the div element, should I?

If you want that new element to react to a click then yes you need to tell the system that. I see a load of new code added, where is that called from?

@AHaworth, the event handler is called whenever a cell on the bard is clicked, it is inside a for loop

firstly the event.target is the cell, inside of that cell is a div which contains the "gold-piece" class, however the target's class itself is not gold-piece, event.target.classList.contains('gold-piece') should always return false to check if any of the child of a target contains the class you should use the same logic as for removing the original:
event.target.querySelector('div.gold-piece') !== null;

